# Comparación de campos de diferentes tablas en Mysql o MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, trigger

Buen día, como puedo comparar los campos de dos tablas diferentes. Tengo las siguientes 2 tablas:

STOCK (id, nombre, cantidad)
y
PEDIDOS(id, id_stock, cantidad)

Lo que quiero hacer es que solo se puedan insertar datos en la tabla PEDIDOS si la cantidad que se quiere insertar es menor o igual a la cantidad de la tabla STOCK.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
/*La estructura de las tablas es la siguiente*/

create table STOCK(
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    nombre varchar(50),
    cantidad int
);

create table PEDIDOS(
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    id_stock int,
    cantidad int,
    foreign key(id_stock) references STOCK(id)
);

/*Aqui es donde intento hacer la comparacion con un trigger*/

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trig1 BEFORE INSERT ON PEDIDOS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

/*EN LA LINEA DE ABAJO ME DA ERROR NO SE COMO HACER LA COMPARACION 
ENTRE LOS CAMPOS DE LAS DOS TABLAS CON EL IF*/

    IF NEW.cantidad > STOCK.cantidad THEN 
        update STOCK set STOCK.cantidad = SOTCK.cantidad - new.cantidad
        where STOCK.id = new.id_stock;
    END IF;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

No puedes solo poner **STOCK.cantidad** por que no estás referenciando ninguna tabla, lo que puedes hacer es ir a buscar el valor del campo cantidad con una consulta y luego comparas que la cantidad a insertar sea igual o menor a ese valor.

```
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER trig1 BEFORE INSERT ON PEDIDOS
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN


        IF NEW.cantidad <= (select cantidad from STOCK where id = new.id_stock)  THEN 
          update STOCK set STOCK.cantidad = STOCK.cantidad - new.cantidad
          where STOCK.id = new.id_stock;
        END IF;

    END $$
    DELIMITER ;
```